# Display every single combination of lower case letters

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out how to print every single combination of lower case letters starting at A, B, C , .. , Z AA, AB , .., ZZ ... AAA, AAB, AAC ... HWESA, HWESB, HWESC ... etc and I want the program to keep printing these endlessly, growing in length by 1 each time Z is found as the last letter.

Code that is have seen online is like this

```
for(int a = 0; a < alphabet.length; a++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(alphabet[a]);
    for(int b = 0; b < alphabet.length; b++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(alphabet[a]+alphabet[b]);
        //With however many for loops you want which correspond to string length
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't work for me because I want the length to go till infinite (or in my program to stop when it matches a hard-coded string).

Comment: You've stated a goal. But you haven't told us what problem you encountered while trying to implement this. Therefore, you do not have a valid question for this website. I suggest you try to implement it. If you get stuck, provide a [MCVE] and specifically describe the part you're stuck at, what errors you're getting etc.

Comment: Alright, that can be done, what have you tried to do?

Comment: I recommend you start with the theory.  Once you understand the Math then you can focus on creating a program from this.  Look at combinatorics.  Once you studied enough to formulate a good math question then try:  https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @mason I have updated the question can it be resumed?

Comment: @RonBeyer I have updated the question to put some code I have tried but it doesnt give flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same in java with recursive method , hope you understand the logic and write down in C#.You can check the whole program in the below shared link.

size - if 1 means a,b,c...z
       if 2 means aa,ab...zz

```
public static void recursion(long size,String prefix)//Recursive method
    {   
    // Base case: size is 0, print prefix
    if(size==0)
    {   System.out.println(prefix);
        return;
    }
     // One by one add all characters from set and recursively 
    // call for size equals to size-1
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
         // Next character of input added
        String newPrefix = prefix + s[i];
         // Size is decreased, because we have added a new character
        recursion(size-1,newPrefix);
    }

}
```

[Click Here to View Full Code](https://github.com/Rishabh-Rathod/Alphabets/blob/master/Alphabets/alphamagic.java)